# How can developing countries put their concerns on the IMF board's agenda or get their views taken into account during board discussions?

Tags: international-monetary-fund

Contrarily to organizations such as the WTO, the power is skewed towards developed and major countries like China, which also have the most voting power. There seems to be a lack of effective participation by many of the developing countries, Sub-Saharan African countries in particular, in the decision making processes of the Executive Board. Because I don't know how the Executive Board operate, I don't know how developing countries can put their concerns onto the table or get their views taken into account during board discussions at the IMF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to believe the IMF is (or should be) a democratic institution. It isn't. It is a shareholder-controlled monetary institution managed by those who *paid* into it. That is why rich countries get one member each while all of Africa gets to select two. Groupings of countries wich represent slightly over 3% and less than 2% of votes each select one Executive Director while e.g. Saudi Arabia alone has more than 2% of the votes.

So to your question, they get heard through their regional representative.